# How to modify Gaussian Z-matrix to adjust distances between monomers

Tags: gaussian, visualization-software

I am trying to make a script to adapt and modify the distances between two monomers I do have. I have build a xyz structure and use Openbabel to construct the Z-matrix of the system. However, I am not sure if there is a simple way of modifying it to adapt the distances of the monomers. For example, for two water molecules, which zmatrix is given by:

```
0 1
O1
H2 1 r1
H3 1 r2 2 a1
O5 2 r3 4 a2 1 180.
H6 5 r4 2 a3 4 d1
H7 5 r4 2 a3 4 -d1
Variables
r1 = 1.0
r2 = 1.0
r3 = 1.8
r4 = 1.0
a1 = 104.52
a2 = 90.
a3 = 120.
d1 = 80.
```

How would you proceed if you want to keep varying the distances using a small "distance step" to compute properties of the system? For example, between atom 2 and 5.

Comment: My recommendation is to use a script language (or Bash) and generate the Z matrix file from it. In the script you can do the calculations for the distances and angles you are interested in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general problem with auto-generated z-matrices (e.g., this one) is that they may not define distances the way you want.

In this case, it seems as if you just need to change `r3`.

Gaussian, like many programs, has built-in support for energy scans.

`r3 1.8  10 0.1`

This would take 10 steps, each 0.1 in size. This has the advantage of starting each step with a good initial guess for SCF from the previous geometry.

More generally, even as an Open Babel developer, I agree with the comment by @Camps. Pick your favorite script language (e.g., Python) and you can move distances and angles as you wish.

Pseudo-code:

```
# write xyz coordinates of one monomer
for step in range(10):
    for atom in monomer1:
        new_xyz = atom.xyz + [ step * 0.1, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        # write out atom at new_xyz
```